# Prove Existence Periodic Solution Nonlinear Pendulum with Torque

Tags: nonlinear-system, periodic-functions, closed-map

Suppose we have the following system
$$ \theta'=v $$
$$ v'= -bv - \sin\theta + k. $$
I need to prove that there exists a periodic solution in the region where $k>1$.

The hint that was given is to look at a strip 
$$ v_1 < (k - \sin\theta)/b < v_2. $$
I think I need to use the Poincaré-Bendixon Theorem that states that if $\Omega$ is a closed and bounded limit set of a planar system of differential equations that contains no equilibrium point, then $\Omega$ is a closed orbit.

Any ideas how I can work this out properly?